# Entity Framework attempting to perform a migration when one is not needed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application whose database is built using Code First Entity Framework. I recently made some small front-end validation updates the application, which were deployed to the test environment successfully with no issues. However on deploying the same application to the live environment the application fails with an "Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss." error.

I didn't create any migrations as part of this update, nor have any migrations been created since the application's last deployment to either the test or live environments - the MigrationHistory table in each database lists all of the migrations that have been performed thus far, with no migrations outstanding. I brought a copy of the live database down onto my development machine for testing purposes, but the error does not occur there even when using the live database that the same code says needs to be migrated.

I have a couple of questions - does anybody know what circumstances cause this kind of issue, and is there a way to resolve it without affecting the content of the live database?

Comment: is your automatic migration conditional or you do not need it at all?

Comment: Hi @MandarJogalekar, the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled setting was set to True without any conditions on it. I've temporarily "resolved" the issue by setting this to False so I can deploy the application to the live environment, but the underlying issue is still there.